# XSLT 2.0 paramer list/map with for each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">

    <xsl:param name="childPath"/>
    <xsl:param name="childNode"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()=$childNode]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($childPath)//class"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is that I have one parent (template) xml file and N child xml files. So, I take parent and call this xslt file for the first child xml file, for the second and so on. This xslt file I call using maven-xml-plugin and for every call I need to set transormationSet that is rather verbose.

So, I want to call this xslt file only once and pass all parameters as a list or a map. For example

```
$childNodes = nodeOne;nodeTwo;nodeThree
$childPaths = pathOne;pathTwo;pathTree
```

or like map:

```
$children = nodeOne:pathOne;nodeTwo:pathTwo
```

Could anyone say how to make my xslt file work with such list/map parameters?

Comment: Which version of which XSLT processor do you use exactly? Saxon 9.8 and later and AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later support XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 maps. e.g. `<xsl:param name="children" select="map { 'nodeOne' : 'pathOne', 'nodeTwo' : 'pathTwo' }"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I use net.sf.saxon 8.7. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/saxon)

Comment: That is even a pre XSLT 2 release.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I can use this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/10.3 if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 map, as supported in Saxon 9.8 and later or Saxon-JS 2 or Altova XML 2017 R3 and later you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="children" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" select="map { 'nodeOne' : 'pathOne', 'nodeTwo' : 'pathTwo' }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()=map:keys($children)]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document($children(local-name()))//class"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an alternative to stick with your string values containing semicolon separated lists of values:

```
  <xsl:param name="childNodes">nodeOne;nodeTwo;nodeThree</xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:param name="childPaths">pathOne;pathTwo;pathTree</xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="childNodesSeq" select="tokenize($childNodes, ';')"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="childPathsSeq" select="tokenize($childPaths, ';')"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()=$childNodesSeq]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document($childPathsSeq[index-of($childNodesSeq, local-name(current()))])//class"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you say in what format should I pass children. I mean `<parameter>                                    <name>children</name><value>'nodeOne':'pathOne'</value></parameter>`? I asking as I get `supplied value ... is an atomic value`.

Comment: @Shtirlits, how/from where do you pass parameters? From Saxon's command line? From a Java program? If so, which API do you use? In Java code I would use https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map-.

Comment: I use maven-xml-plugin, see parameters section here https://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/transform-parameters.html

Comment: @Shtirlits, sorry, I don't know how they represent XDM 2 or XDM 3.1 values in their parameter mechanism, consider to tag your question appropriately to find expertise on that particular topic.

Comment: Ok, I see. But how would it be represented for java command line? Maybe it is the same...

Comment: Or maybe it is possible to create map from string in xslt?

Comment: https://github.com/mojohaus/xml-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/xml/TransformMojo.java#L542 suggests they use String for both parameter names and values so I am afraid they don't support the more advanced XPath 2 or XPath 3.1 type system at all. You could only try to use a string with JSON `<parameter><name>children</name><value>{"nodeOne" : "pathOne", "nodeTwo" : "pathTwo"}</value></parameter>` and parse it with `<xsl:param name="children"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="children-map" select="parse-json($children)"/>`.

Comment: And then use `map:keys($children-map)`  and `document($children-map(local-name()))`.

Comment: I would probably pass the parameter value as a string containing a JSON representation of the map, and parse it within the XSLT using parse-json().

Comment: I did this `<xsl:param name="children"/><xsl:variable name="children-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" select="parse-json($children)"/>` and this `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()=map:keys($children-map)]"><xsl:apply-templates select="document($children-map(local-name()))//class"/></xsl:template>`. And pass parameter this way `<parameter><name>children</name><value>{"nodeOne":"pathOne"}</value></parameter>`. No errors. However, child node is only removed from template but child content is not inserted in template.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think, it is what I am doing now. But it doesn't work. Something is wrong with map or map value.

Comment: @Shtirlits, the XSLT side, assuming Saxon 9.8 or later, should be fine, see it working at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDh. So either the parameter passing in Maven somehow preparses/processes the `<value>{"nodeOne":"pathOne"}</value>` or something else is going wrong.

Comment: It is strange. When I set incorrect path I get `Error at char 9 in expression in xsl:apply-templates/@select on line 15 column 83 of persistence.xsl:
  FODC0002  I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  file:/*deleted*/myfile.x2ml: /*deleted*/myfile.x2ml (No such file or directory). Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /*deleted*/myfile.x2ml (No such file or directory)
  In template rule with match="*[map:keys(...) = fn:local-name(...)]" on line 14 of persistence.xsl
     invoked by built-in template rule (shallow-copy)
     invoked by built-in template rule (shallow-copy)`

Comment: So, map is parsed, child xml file is read, but why its content not inserted???

Comment: @Shtirlits, you have an `xpath-default-namespace` in place, are both XML documents in that set namespace? Otherwise, you have to override the namespace with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates xpath-default-namespace="" select="document($children-map(local-name()))//class"/>` for no namespace in the second document or e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/ns" select="document($children-map(local-name()))//class"/>` for a particular namespace in the second document.

Comment: Yes, setting `xpath-default-namespace` solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to introduce a template mode and iterate over the name / path pairs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">

    <xsl:param name="children" select="'name1:path1;name2:path2'"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="here" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($children,';')">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="child" select="$here">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" tunnel="true" select="tokenize(.,':')[1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="path" tunnel="true" select="tokenize(.,':')[2]"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="child">
        <xsl:param name="name" tunnel="true"/>
        <xsl:param name="path" tunnel="true"/>

        <xsl:if test="local-name()=$name">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document($path)//class"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="child"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```